# Can imperatives function as interjections?

Tags: imperative-sentences, interjections

I have no direct example, but sentences like 'Look! it doesn't work,' and 'listen! I have no time' make me wonder if imperatives can function as interjections, so a comma can be between an imperative and a sentence as in 'look, it doesn't work.'

Comment: (nearly) anything can be an interjection.

Comment: "Look! It doesn't work." That seems to me like the speaker is pointing out a faulty device. On the other hand "Look, it doesn't work" seems like part of a discussion about whether to fix it. "Look" seems to be just adding emphasis to the sentence.